# Why is spring batch looking for hsqldb

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am writing a spring batch application where I am using Oracle as the data store. When running the build and spring loads up, it is looking for hsqldb although I have defined ORACLE as the databaseType. Here is the error in the logs:
Cannot load JDBC driver class `org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver`

I do not want to use a separate database to store the spring batch meta-data.
Please advise why is spring batch looking for hsqldb.

```
 <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="paymentDataSource"/>
    <property name="databaseType" value="ORACLE" />
 </bean>

<bean id="paymentDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver">
    </property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@boxxxx:1521:xxxxx">
    </property>
    <property name="username" value="xxx"></property>
    <property name="password" value="xxx"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" />

[java] org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Unable to initialize group definition. Group resource name [classpath*:beanRefContext.xml], factory key [applicationContext-main]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'baseContext' defined in URL : Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver'
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:388)
     [java]     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.loadParentContext(ContextLoader.java:563)
     [java]     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
     [java]     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
```

Comment: The exception states that the beanRefContext.xml can not create the bean baseContext because the jobRepository bean that is getting instantiated can't load the HSQLDB driver. 

Seems like the job metadata is trying to persist batch job information to the inmemory database which it cannot find the driver for, regardless of your oracle db config

Please provide more information (pom.xml and applicable xml wiring). 

For more information on how to store job repository information in memory checkout https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureJob.html#inMemoryRepository

Comment: Is this a Boot app?

Comment: Thanks @Sander_M. You are right. Spring Batch needs HSQLDB to manage the in memory state of the the Job Repository. Once I added the dependency in maven, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already defined the corresponding property in `application.properties` ?

For example:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

And the dependency of Oracle JAR in your `pom.xml` ?